# What do I call this "heel fixture" used for attaching a pallet rack column to the floor?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, translation

I'm translating a text about a pallet racking system. One sentence goes like this:

> Крепление стеллажей к полу осуществить через металлические **подпятники** с помощью химических анкеров.
>
> Attach the racks to the floor via metallic "**underheels**" using chemical anchors.

I googled and these "[underheels](http://%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84/dopolnitelnoe-oborudovanie/333-podpyatnik-stoyki-stellazha.html)" look like the ones in the pictures below. The metallic thingies bolted to the pallet rack columns. These metallic thingies are then attached to the concrete floor using chemical anchors.

What do I call them in English? Multitran's entry for [подпятник](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EF%EE%E4%EF%FF%F2%ED%E8%EA) has many options, and I don't know which to pick.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would call them "anchors".

Comment: @HotLicks - no, the sentence already mentions **chemical anchors**. The "underheels" are the metallic "boots" that are bolted to the rack columns.

Comment: "Anchors" is what I would call them in English.  The chemical is "adhesive".

Comment: @HotLicks as far as I understand, by "chemical anchors" the authors mean [bolts combined with adhesive chemicals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3SfG6Kl2h4). And they seem to be called [chemical anchors](https://www.chemical-anchors.com) in English.. although I only came across the term today.

Comment: @HotLicks - maybe I should call the metallic pad thingies "anchor plates" to distinguish them from "chemical anchors" (bolts)

Comment: You're getting everything confused.  That (slightly strange) web page is referring purely to the chemical, not the bolt.  The stuff most people would call "anchor adhesive".  But calling the pads "anchor plates" (or "anchor pads") would be understood by most readers.  However, this question really belongs on [Home Improvement SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) or some such.

Comment: @HotLicks - "A couple of other options are chemical anchors and adhesive anchors, which involve a substance being poured into the hole along with the bolt."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are called *baseplates*.

> BASEPLATES
>
> An upright frame has at least (2) baseplates used to anchor the pallet rack to the floor for stability.  The size of the baseplate is based on seismic forces and the loads placed on the pallet rack.  Engineers should check the design to make sure the proper baseplate is specified for the pallet racking.

[UNARCO: Components of a Rack System](http://www.unarcorack.com/pallet-rack-warehouse-storage/components-pallet-rack-system/)

Answer (score 4):

I thought it would be called a *flange*, but it seems that *90-degree mounting plate* or *mounting bracket* is a better fit.